# I Want Make The UserControl On Canvas When i Click the Add button

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I try so many time but still can not work it

Here is my Canvas Code in MainWindow.Xaml

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ic" ItemsSource="{Binding StkObjects}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ShelfViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <UC:UCShelf Width="{Binding Width}"
                                    Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PortViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <UC:UCPort Width="{Binding Width}"
                                   Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Gray"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

I think this Xaml is not have any problem

And this is my Button function

```
    private void AddShelf()
    {
        var shelfViewModel = new ShelfViewModel
        {
            Top = ((_stkObjects.Count + 1) * 100),
            Left = ((_stkObjects.Count + 1) * 100),
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
        };

        var userControl = new UCShelf();
        userControl.DataContext = shelfViewModel;

        var item = new ItemViewModel
        {
            UserControl = userControl,
            Top = shelfViewModel.Top,
            Left = shelfViewModel.Left,
            Width = shelfViewModel.Width,
            Height = shelfViewModel.Height,
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        StkObjects.Add(item);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StkObjects));
            Debug.WriteLine("StkObjects updated on UI thread. Count: " + _stkObjects.Count);
        });
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StkObjects));
    }
```

The StkObjects mean is a ObservableCollection

and the ItemViewModel is have
UserControl,Top,Left,Width,Height

information use get and set

And my UserControl use DataContext the other ViewModel

(Ex UserControl Name : AControl, DataContext : AViewModel)

i Check the Visual Tree in Visual Studio it is not any reaction

but the StkObjects.Count is works...so i think some binding is wrong..

but i can't find the problem..

i try solve this problem 1 weeks but i can't fint the answer

Comment: In MVVM you don't handle any UI elements in your view model. Please read [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to understand how you create controls dynamically in WPF by defining a DataTemplate. This will also solve your issues.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Isn't the UCShelf  control displayed? Notre that the UCShelf that is created inside the DataTemplate is not the same instance that you create in the view model. Your view model must not create any instances or reference any instances of UCShelf or  UI elements in general. Why do you need this reference in your view model?

Comment: You should also remove the Dispatcher.Invoke part. The Dispatcher is not needed.

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StkObjects));` is redundant too and only causes harm. Since the source collection is a ObservableCollection the binding will cause the ItemsControl to update any time the collection has changed.

Comment: When you apply MVVM design rules strictly and use DataTemplates you will fix your current issue.